# OnHover show - content of div - without using space before hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

The problem is: I want to make a "menuthing" that should hover the submenuitem, if the parent activate a hover event like I got it here:

HTML:

```
<div id="menuitem">Info</div>
<div id="menuitem">Foto</div>
<div id="menuitem">Sicherheit im Web</div>
<div id="menuitem">Projekte
    <div id="submenuitem">SchülerInnenparlament
        <div id="subsubmenuitem">
            <a href="./subsubitem1.html">Aktuelles</a>
        </div>
        <div id="subsubmenuitem">
            <a href="./subsubitem2.html">Text should be written here</a>
        </div>
        <div id="subsubmenuitem">
            <a href="./subsubitem3.html">Text should be written here1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="menuitem" title="E-Learning">E-Learning</div>
<div id="menuitem" title="Kontakt">Kontakt</div>
```

CSS:

```
#subsubmenuitem
{
    opacity:0;   
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}
#submenuitem {
    opacity:0;   
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}
#menuitem:hover #submenuitem {
    opacity:1;
}
#submenuitem:hover #subsubmenuitem {
    opacity:1;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Bpur/1/

But the content of the div is using the space under the menuitem. It should move the other divs down - not just make the thing invisible.
Anybody know a solution for this one?

Edit:

```
ul
    li
    li
/ul
```

would be better?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are you talking about showing/hiding the submenus, just use:

`display: none`

`display: block`

View results in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3YWB4/) demo.

### CSS

```
#subsubmenuitem,
#submenuitem 
{
    display: none;
    opacity:0;   
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
}
#menuitem:hover #submenuitem,
#submenuitem:hover #subsubmenuitem 
{
    display: block;
    opacity:1;
}
```

---

Or since display can't be transitioned, try using `height` and `overflow` like in this [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7Lsrs/) demo.

### CSS

```
#submenuitem,
#subsubmenuitem
{
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    transition:.5s;
    
    opacity: 0; 
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#menuitem:hover #submenuitem,
#submenuitem:hover #subsubmenuitem 
{
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: ohw damed.. you are right. thanks - next problem is this: I want that the submenuitems will be shown at the end of the whole menuitems. So if you hover over the first it will be shown at the end (only the menu/submenu)

Comment: I didn't notice you were transitioning, so I added another solution that gives you that effect and still removes the gap.

Comment: I think i have to show you the thing i want to create... here are some screenshots of the "how it should look"-design:
The Menu:
http://adtime.at/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Bildschirmfoto-2013-11-06-um-20.19.42.png
The Submenu hovered (orange one and cursor on SchülerInnen...):
http://adtime.at/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Bildschirmfoto-2013-11-06-um-20.20.03.png
The Sebmenu hovered (orange one and cursor on Comenius...)
http://adtime.at/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Bildschirmfoto-2013-11-06-um-20.20.29.png

Comment: There is no way to do this without javascript?

Comment: Are you saying you want all sub-sub-menus shown when the sub-menu is hovered?

Comment: It should be like:
1. Picture Menu
2. Hovered on the Orange one (show Submenus under the menuitems)
3. Hovered on the first Submenu (show subsubmenu of this submenu between the submenus)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40658/discussion-between-domi-and-scott)

Comment: I answered what you originally asked and I'm afraid what you are asking for now would constitute an entirely new question. That said, a question like that would require someone provide you with a complete solution, which would go against the rules of this site.  You should at least attempt to create what you are asking for yourself. At that point, you would be able to post a question showing what you've tried, why you think it isn't working, and what you are expecting. Sorry I couldn't be of more help, but I would appreciate an upvote for solving your original issue, if you would be so kind =D

Comment: I will give you a shove in the right direction, though.  You are most likely going to need to seek out a solution using fixed height/widths and absolute positioning to achieve what you are now asking.

Comment: 1. Gave you the upvote of course ;)
2. You are right - the original question was answered - now I will ask a second questions because i'm standing on an (really good) point put don't get it on the right position ;)

Comment: I appreciate it! Good luck! I'm at work or I'd help you more.  Maybe if I get some time tonite, I'll take another look.

Comment: Also, take a look at using `display:table`, `display:table-cell`, `display:inline-block` and forget about floats.  Something I noticed in your html too, you use the same `id` over and over for all items of that level.  You can't do that.  Switch the `id` attribute to `class`.

Comment: I made it much cleaner now - but also with floating have a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19822383/menu-show-up-the-submenuitems-under-the-whole-menuitems and now i'm edited the "display:inline-block" thanks :)