# Menu - Show up the Submenuitems under the whole Menuitems - HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The menuitems are picture like this with `display: inline-block;` & `padding-right:10px` to get them in one line

[image: Menuitems]
They are in a "ul/li architecture" which looks like this:

```
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><img src="./information.jpg" height="120" width="*"></img></li>
            <li><img src="./fotos.jpg" height="120" width="*"></img></li>
            <li><img src="./security.jpg" height="120" width="*"></img></li>
            <li><img src="./projekt.jpg" height="120" width="*"></img></li>
            <li><img src="./elearning.jpg" height="120" width="*"></img></li>
            <li><img src="./kontakt.jpg" height="120" width="*"></img></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Now i'm trying to make a submenu that should look like this:
[image: Menu with Submenuitems]
That's what should happen if you click on the lightbulb-picture. So it should push the content of the whole page down and set himself under the menuitems. How can I do this? I tried it with putting an `ul` into the `li` with the lightbulb and tried it to get it there via css. Is it posible to but the Submenu on other position but also link it with the mainmenu?

Comment: No that's a website using css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as above in the questions:
Menuitems:

```
<div id="info">
    <a href="#"><img src="./information.jpg" height="120" width="*"></img></a>
</div>
<div id="foto">
    <a href="#"><img src="./fotos.jpg" height="120" width="*"></img></a>
</div>
<div id="security">
    <a href="#"><img src="./security.jpg" height="120" width="*"></img></a>
</div>
...
```

After this:

```
<div id="infosub">
    <div class="submenu">submenuitem1</div></br>
    <div class="submenu">submenuitem2</div></br>
    <div class="submenu">submenuitem3</div>
</div>
<div id="fotosub">
    <div class="submenu">submenuitem1</div></br>
    <div class="submenu">submenuitem2</div></br>
    <div class="submenu">submenuitem3</div>
</div>
    ...
```

And via stylesheet: `display:none` on the submenuitems. now you can toggle the whole thing with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(
function() {
    $("#info").click(function() {
        $("#infosub").toggle(1000);
    });
    $("#foto").click(function() {
        $("#fotosub").toggle(1000);
    });
    $("#security").click(function() {
        $("#securitysub").toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

The 1000 in toggle() means the speed with it's going to hide or appear (1000 ms).

With some CSS for the Submenuitems the side looks exactly like the screenshot above - hope it will help you.

Domi

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if you absolutely want to use `ul` `li`. If not, this is how i would do it without javascript. I would use label with hidden checkbox and use the active state to show/hide a div under. So you can style them easily with css. This will push the content down and show whatever you want. In this case, your submenu will appear under your image by pushing the content down.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PG7yv/) is a jsfiddle.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer - few seconds ago i figured it out how i can do this with javascript and also with transient (jquery hide) so i will post my answer too - gave you an upvote ;)